# Newton-Raphson method in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, newtons-method

I want to implement Newton-Raphson method in Mathematica.

Here is my code:

```
f[x] = x^3 - x^2 + 1

MetodaTangente[x0_, eps_] := Block[{p0, p1, dp, k},
   p0 = N[x0];
   p1 = p0;
   dp = 1;
   k = 0;
   While[dp > eps,
    p0 = p1;
    p1 = p0 - f[p0]/f'[p0];
    dp = Abs[p1 - p0];
    k = k + 1;
    ];
   Print[p1];
   ];
```

`k` counts how many iterations was there.

However, here's what happens when I run this:

[image]

It seems that there's a problem with `f`. What should I do now?

Comment: This Mathworld page - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html - contains a much more Mathematica-idiomatic implementation of this method.  So too, if memory serves, does the Mathematica documentation but I don't have that available right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your function like this instead:

```
f[x_] := x^3 - x^2 + 1
MetodaTangente[-1, .000000000001]

> -0.754878
```

More info:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html